# It's better to use BIT or BOOLEAN fro YES/NOT values in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

1) In my table I have a column that set privileges of the users.

I want have a flag 1/0 (yes/not,true/false and so on..) for my privileges (for example: if the user is admin or mod...).

I searched a lot, I'm still confused about the differences about boolean and bit in terms of resources requests to the DBMS. Which is better?

I also found a lot of question of pasted years, so I'd like to have a fresh answer, in case that something it's changed/improved.

2) Another question...

I tryied to use both of these types and I saw that with boolean, it's easy to check if the value is true or false, but I haven't figured out how to see the value of a variable BIT.
I'm my database coloumn I put values 1 or 0, but with a echo of the bit variable, nothing is shown.

So, how can I see the value of a bit (I need to use only 1 or 0).

Thank you in advice!

Comment: 1. [`BOOLEAN` is just an alias for `TINYINY(1)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html#idm139771654994384); 2. Read [`BIT` type documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-type.html); 3. Consider use of [`SET` type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html) if you have got more than a one flag.

Comment: try to find it before asking http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15801/bit-vs-boolean-columns

Comment: Please don't add `[SOLVED]` to question titles.

Comment: @TheBlueDog can I ask you why not?

Comment: No problem at all, things work a bit differently here as opposed to your average Q&A forum. No harm done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TINYINT(1)`. It's what's most commonly used for boolean values. Bear in mind though that it allows for values beyond 1 and 0 so for the sake of consistency I'd suggest using the keywords `TRUE` and `FALSE` when inserting data in it as they reflect `1` and `0`.

`BOOL` and `BOOLEAN` are just synonyms for `TINYINT(1)`. `BIT` on the other hand *used* to be a synonym for `TINYINT(1)` before version 5.0.3.

Comment: Thank you so much! Clear answer :D